# Using characters in a conditional statement in C++

Tags: c++, char, conditional-statements, character

I am trying to write a program which asks for tuition credits and for undergraduate or graduate classes. User enters the number of credits, then must enter `U` for undergraduate or `G` for graduate. I am having issues with the conditional statement, if the user enters `U`, then the price of the undergraduate credits will compute and output, similar with graduate. I am trying to enter `U` at the IF condition, but either one price or the other outputs.

```
#include <stdlib.h>                             
#include <iostream.h>                          

int main ()                                    
{                                             
 const double Under = 380.00 ; 
 const double Grad = 395.00 ;
 char U , G ; 
 double First, Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth, Sixth ;

 cout << endl << endl ;       
 cout << " To calculate your tuition enter the amount of credits, then enter type of"  ; 
 cout << endl ; 
 cout << " classes." ; 

 cout << endl << endl ; 
 cout << " Enter number of credits. " ; 
 cin >> First ; 
 cout << endl << endl ;

 cout << " Enter U for Undergraduate or G for Graduate: " ; 
 cin >> Second ; 

 cout << endl << endl ; 
 cout << " Your tuition total is: " ; 

 Third = First * Under ; 

 Fourth = First * Grad ; 

 if ( Second == U )
 cout << Third ;

 else 
 cout << Fourth ; 
 cout << endl << endl ; 

 system ("Pause");                      

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I see a few problems here.

The main one is that characters in C++ have single quotes, like this `'c'`. This is most likely the cause of your error. Since you never initialized U anywhere, either do initialize it to `'U'` or try

```
if ( Second == 'U' )
    cout << Third ;
```

Second, though this is not necessarily an error typing `cout<<endl<<endl;` is a little wasteful as it flushes the buffer for cout twice with only 1 character added in between. typing `cout<<'\n'<<endl;` would fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You never give a value to `U`. Right now its content is garbage which is why you get random behavior. Try either assigning `'U'` to your variable `U` or changing the confiditional to:

```
if( Second == 'U' )
```

Answer (score 1):

It is more or less all of the already stated:

1. Remove the declaration of `char U` since it is never used
2. Change the type of `Second` to `char` (remove from the `double` list and add `char
   Second;`)
3. Change the if statement to `if ( ( Second == 'U' ) || (
       Second == 'u' ) )`

Comment: Thanks Mario, I see where i made my mistake. I was expecting Second to return a character without declaring it and i also like that the user can use a capital and lower case 'U'. Thanks for you assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `U = 'U'` anywhere. You is declared at beginning, but never initialized. You `U` is just a variable. You have to assign the character `'U'` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Second is declared as a double, but it looks like you are expecting the user to enter a character.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
using namespace std;
```

under header file